# Perfect option scammed

Tags: private-blockchains

I have been scammed from the platform Perfect Option. 
Does anyone else have any dealings with them? 
I am interested to find out further information

Answer (score 3):

They're an obvious scam. I mean, absurdly obvious.

I'm really baffled how anyone could fall for something like this. If someone had a way to reliably invest $10,000 and turn it into $120,000 in a month, what would they want *your* money for?

At that rate, $10,000 would become over $800 quadrillion dollars in just a year, 2,400 times the amount of money that there is in the entire world! Why would they bother setting up a web site and dealing with customers?

Investing always involves a risk/reward trade-off. If there was some way to get large rewards without taking large risks, everyone would do that and be rich. But that's obviously impossible -- there is no economic engine with that capacity. The planet would be entirely owned by every random person with $10,000 to invest in less than year. Where would all those planets full of yachts and mansions come from?

So such a low risk, high reward system doesn't exist. It can't exist. It is so many orders of magnitude outside of the bounds of what is even conceivable, much less possible.

There are a lot of copy/paste scam websites like this. They all have the same red flags all over them. Untraceable testimonials, bad English, no identifiable people in their management, and paragraphs of meaningless mumbo-jumbo.

But most importantly, there is no way anyone could tell what level of risk they would be taking even if the offer was legitimate. Of course, it can't be legitimate, because it doesn't tell you what risks you are taking. Anyone who understood what investment was should be able to immediately tell this is not a legitimate investment because the risks are not clearly disclosed.

If this were possible, nobody would ever have to live in debt. Just borrow $10,000 and next month you have $120,000. You could pay back the $10,000 loan, pay off $100,000 in debt, and have leftover to live off for the next month. Of course, nobody would be in debt -- why would anyone lend anyone $10,000 if they could invest it and have $120,000 in a month? Why would mortgages exist?

Seriously, I have to slap my forehead that people could think this is legitimate. I don't mean to be mean, but geez.